# MaterialUI - how to change styles of checked thumb

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change style of checked thumb, but i cant figure how. I tried every variation.

When thumb is checked, it should change size to width: 20, height: 20 and color: white..

Can someone provide working example or change my code? Thanks!

```
const StyledSwitch = styled((props: SwitchProps) => (
      <Switch focusVisibleClassName=".Mui-focusVisible" disableRipple {...props} />
    ))(({}) => ({
      width: 42,
      height: 26,
      padding: 0,
      marginRight: -16,
      '& .MuiSwitch-switchBase': {
        padding: 3,
        margin: 2,
        transitionDuration: '300ms',
        '& .MuiSwitch-thumb': {
          boxSizing: 'border-box',
          width: 16,
          height: 16,
          boxShadow: 'none',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        '&.Mui-checked': {
          transform: 'translateX(16px)',
          color: '#fff',
          '& + .MuiSwitch-track': {
            backgroundColor: '#00519E',
            opacity: 1,
            border: '2px solid #00519E',
          },
          '&.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track': {
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
        },
        '&.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track': {
          opacity: 0.7,
        },
      },
    
      '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
        borderRadius: 26 / 2,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        border: '2px solid #00519E',
        opacity: 1,
      },
    }));
    
    interface FormSwitchProps extends SwitchProps {
      name?: string;
    }
    
    const FormSwitch: React.FC<FormSwitchProps> = ({ name, ...props }) => (
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<StyledSwitch name={name} {...props} />}
        label={<span className="ml-1">{name}</span> || ''}
      />
    );
    
    export default FormSwitch;
```